# Linear independence is preserved under linear transformations with trivial kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The exercise I'm trying to prove is:

> If $T:V\to W$ is a linear transformation with $\ker T=\{0_V\}$. If $v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_k  \in V$ are linearly independent, then $T(v_1),T(v_2),\cdots, T(v_k) \in W$ are also linearly independent.

What I've tried to analyze from this, is that, if $\ker T=\{0_V\}$ and $v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_k\in V$ are linearly independent, then, $v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_kv_k=0_V=\ker T$ is a linear combination where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_i=0$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,k.$

Should that imply that $T(v)=0_W$ for all $v\in V$? And since $T(v)=0_W$, does that imply that $T(v)=0_W=b_1w_1+b_2w_2+\cdots+b_kw_k$ and hence $T(v_1),T(v_2),\cdots,T(v_k)$ are linearly independent elements of $W$?

Also, at this point I'm not really sure if it's really necessary to define $\ker T=\{0_V\}$ since we're already saying that $v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_k  \in V$ are linearly independent. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that
$$b_1T(v_1)+\cdots+b_kT(v_k)=0$$
holds for some constants $b_1,..,b_k$. You can rewrite this as
$$T(b_1v_1+\cdots b_kv_k)=0$$
Can you now use your assumption on the kernel of $T$ and finish the proof?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not seeing it at first glance, but when you are assuming that $T(b_1v_1+\cdots b_kv_k)=0$ holds for some constants $b_1,..,b_k$, you are substituting the part where I said that $0_W=b_1w_1+b_2w_2+\cdots+b_kw_k$ right? Also, when you asked if with my assumption on the kernel of T I could finish the proof, are you referring to this $v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_kv_k=0_V=\ker T$ ? And if so, to finish the proof, should I just say that $T(v)=T(b_1v_1+\cdots b_kv_k)=0_w$?

Comment: Since the kernel of $T$ is trivial you know that $T(v)=0\Rightarrow v=0$. In our case $v=b_1v_1+\cdots+b_kv_k$ so you obtain $b_1v_1+\cdots+b_kv_k=0$. What can you say about the constants $b_1,...,b_k$ if such an equality holds, and the vectors $v_1,..,v_k$ are linearly independent?

Comment: We can say that $b_1,...,b_k=0$.

Comment: Ok then if you have shown that if $b_1T(v_1)+\cdots+b_kT(v_k)=0$ then $b_1=...=b_k=0$. What does that tell you about $T(v_1),...,T(v_k)$?

Comment: It implies that $T(v_1),...,T(v_k)$ is linearly independent.

Comment: I've modified my proof from your observations. Please tell me if there´re any mistakes. The proof reads as follows: Since $kerT=\{0_v\}$, it's known that for $v \in V$, if $T(v)=0_w\Rightarrow v=0_v$ where $v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_kv_k$ for $v_1,..,v_k \in V$ and $a_1,...,a_k \in R$. Since $v=0_v$ and we know that $v_1,..,v_k \in V$ are linearly independent, then $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k=0_v \Rightarrow a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_k=0$. Now, since $T(v)=a_1T(v_1)+\cdots+a_kT(v_k)=0_w$ and we know that $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_k=0$, then $T(v_1),T(v_2),\cdots, T(v_k) \in W$ are also linearly independent.

Comment: You have the proof a bit on its head. You want to show that $T(v_1),...,T(v_k)$ are linearly independent, so start off with $b_1T(v_1)+\cdots+b_kT(v_k)=0$ and show that $b_1=...=b_k$.